# List of child pages fetch next results at link click

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, pages, child-pages

I have a list of child pages which are getting displayed as links to those pages. Im displaying it in a certain div with a maximum of 6 results. What I want is I have a "a href" which is called more... so when clicked I want to fetch and display the next 6 results (so the first 6 are replaced by the next). A button that does it is fine also, how would I do this? What I have so far in a have_posts loop is:

```
$subs = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page'=>6, 'post_parent' => $pid, 'post_type' => 'page',  'orderby' => 'menu_order title' ));

 if( $subs->have_posts() ) : while( $subs->have_posts() ) : $subs->the_post();
 if ($link==get_permalink()) echo '<li><h1><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h1></li>';
else echo '<li><h2><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h2></li>';

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the build in features to page your results

- [`WP_Query` Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)
- [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)
- [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)

Just simply add the `paged` parameter to your query arguments, and don't forget to set the `$max_pages` parameter in `next_posts_link()`